# Options for Map Based Mobile App/Game

Tags: maps, game, mobile, openstreetmap

I'm working on a project for an online map based mobile game. I started with the back-end using AWS Cognito for use authentication, AWS RDS with MySQL for data storage, and AWS Lambda for back-end functionality.

My mobile app will be for Android and iOS and is using Xamarin. I have AWS Cognito hooked up and everything is working fine and dandy so far and I'm calling AWS Lambda functions successfully with a JWT ID token obtained from AWS Cognito.

Neat!

Now I'm at a crucial point where I need to decide what library to use for the map based mobile front-end.

**What the front-end mobile app map will need to do**:

- Render custom 2D textures/images over a real world map based on the user's current location
- Place points on a map which use custom 2D images and animations
- Allow me to place a customized UI on top of the map

Now I am fairly familiar already with google maps and it can do everything I require **except for rendering custom 2D textures**. As far as I know, you can only customize your map with specific colors and not textures/images.

Also, note that the map data I need does not have to be extremely accurate. As long as land and water is separated, that's pretty much all I need as far as map data goes.

What my research has yielded so far is several options for **3D** map based mobile games, but not really any for **2D**. 3D will introduce complexities that I simply do not want to have to deal with in development.

Google has https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/gaming/

And I have found several other libraries which utilize OpenStreetMaps using Unity. Some examples here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Unity

But again, these are all **3D**. I probably don't even really need any sort of game engine. If I can just use custom textures/images on the map then I should have everything else I need.

Does OpenStreetMaps have something which might suit my needs? The OSM libraries I've found don't seem to have great documentation. **What are my options here?**